# PHP insert array dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, array, insert, foreach

```
$arrayValues = $request->estado_id //devuelve un array con 4 posiciones y todas son strings

$query = //sqlQuery
```

intente hacer otro foreach dentro del foreach

```
foreach($query as $data)
    {

      $data->estado_pedido_id   = 2;
      $data->pasaje_estado      = 1;
    //insert $arrayValues here

      foreach($arrayValues as $dataArr => $p_value)
      {
     
       $data->pasaje_estado      = $p_value;
      
      }

    $data->save();
    }
```

El primer foreach hace un insert sobre 4 registros correctamente, lo que yo quiero es que el $arrayValues (que es un array) se haga tambien sobre los 4 registros (lo hace pero inserta para los 4 la ultima posicion del array y deberia insertar para el primero la primer posicion, segundo, segunda posicion, etc.

Comment: Quieres meter valores obtenidos del primer foreach y meterlos a un array?

Comment: Desde el punto de vista lógico el `$data->save();` debería estar dentro del `foreach` interior para que te guarde en cada iteracción. Pero no me gusta ese estilo de modificar objetos una y otra vez dentro de bucles. Sin embargo, sin conocer el contexto no se puede sugerir una solución más óptima.

Comment: El primer foreach hace un insert sobre 4 registros correctamente, lo que yo quiero es que el $arrayValues (que es un array) se haga tambien sobre los 4 registros (lo hace pero inserta para los 4, la ultima posicion del array y deberia insertar para el primero la primer posicion, segundo, segunda posicion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // array lleno 
    $array = array('perro', 'gato', 'avestruz');
    // declaro un array vacio donde metere los valores
    $arrayNuevo = array();

    // $key guarda la posicion del array
    // $value guarda el valor ejem. perro gato ...
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $arrayNuevo[] = $value;
    }
    // imprimo para ver que si existan los datos en el nuevo array
    print_r($arrayNuevo);
?>
```